# Unable to make a transaction with Data using Java api ethSendRawTransaction

Tags: web3j, raw-transaction, java, calldata

I am trying to make a transaction between two different accounts using Java. It works perfectly fine as long as I am not using "Data" parameter.

My intent is not to call a smart contract but to make a value exchange between two parties where I will store small ascii (hex converted) data as a note in every transaction.

If I do not use "Data" parameter api like

> RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction

then it works fine and successfully returns me the transaction hash.

But I would use API like

> RawTransaction.createTransaction

Then I face a JSON error like

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
>        at [Source: buffer(okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource@7905a0b8).inputStream();
>   line: 1, column: 81] (through reference chain:
>   org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthSendTransaction["error"]->org.web3j.protocol.core.Response$Error["data"])

Either I am calling in a wrong way or API has any issue , I would like someone to help to understand how I can make a value exchange transaction without this above problem.

Here is my code

```
//create raw transaction

            //import the address from Ganache's account by using its private key
            String strPrivateKey = "0xc87509a1c067bbde78beb793e6fa76530b6382a4c0241e5e4a9ec0a0f44dc0d3";
            Credentials senderCredentials = Credentials.create(ECKeyPair.create(hexStringToByteArray(strPrivateKey)));
            System.out.println(senderCredentials.getAddress());


            BigInteger amountWei = Convert.toWei("1.789", Convert.Unit.ETHER).toBigInteger();

//Data I am trying to send with transaction to be recorded in DATA part of ethereum transaction
            String Data = Numeric.toHexString("Hey this is me".getBytes());


            EthGetTransactionCount ethGetTransactionCount = web3a.ethGetTransactionCount(
                    senderCredentials.getAddress(), DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get();

            BigInteger nonce = ethGetTransactionCount.getTransactionCount();

            //When I create transaction using below API then it crash at the time of send ethSendRawTransaction
            RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createTransaction(
                    nonce,Transfer.GAS_PRICE,Transfer.GAS_LIMIT, RecieverAddress,amountWei,Data);

            // When I create transaction using this API then it sucessfully work at the time of send call ethSendRawTransaction
           /* RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction(
                   nonce, Transfer.GAS_PRICE, Transfer.GAS_LIMIT, RecieverAddress, amountWei);*/

            byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, senderCredentials);
            String hexValue = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);

//this is the place where I get error 
                EthSendTransaction ethSendTransaction =  web3a.ethSendRawTransaction(hexValue).sendAsync().get();


            String transactionHash = ethSendTransaction.getTransactionHash();

            System.out.println(transactionHash);
```

Comment: the data there is "The compiled code of a contract OR the hash of the invoked method signature and encoded parameters." and not a "message".                  
maybe this could help you https://techblog.bozho.net/send-ethereum-transactions-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the problem using the default GAS limitation. I got this information once I tried Logback. Therefore, I have changed the gas limitation by replacing default Transfer.Gast_LIMIT to  210000L.

```
RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createTransaction(
                    nonce, Transfer.GAS_PRICE, BigInteger.valueOf(210000L), RecieverAddress, amountWei, Data);
```

Afterward, my data worked and stored successfully.

Note:- Make sure to open the logging mechanism to understand proper error otherwise like me you will get

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out

Which doesn't give you much detail about why JSON communication was failed.

Answer (score 0):

From the web3j doc :/

```
RawTransaction.createTransaction(
        <nonce>, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT, "0x<address>", <amount>, "0x<hex encoded text>");

byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, ALICE);
String hexValue = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);

EthSendTransaction ethSendTransaction =
        web3j.ethSendRawTransaction(hexValue).send();
String transactionHash = ethSendTransaction.getTransactionHash();
```